# SQL: Update SortIndex based on other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like that :

```
StepId | VehicleId| Description  | SortIndex
---------------------------
1      |xxx       | Description1 | 0
2      |yyyyy     | Description2 | 0
3      |yyyyy     | Description3 | 0
```

So there can be from 0 to n Steps for one vehicle (referenced by vehicleId).
Until now I ordered the steps by the Description Column. I would now like to update the SortIndex column so they have the values as if I ordered them by the Description Column. So for the example above I would like to have:

```
   StepId | VehicleId| Description  | SortIndex
    ---------------------------
    1      |xxx       | Description1 | 1
    2      |yyyyy     | Description2 | 1
    3      |yyyyy     | Description3 | 2
```

Is there any SQL magic I can do, to achieve this?

Thanks

EDIT: I'm using SQL Server, maybe a cursor will do the job

Comment: Are you using sql server ?

Comment: How do you want to order by the description column? Numerically or alphanumerically? At the moment you are sorting in this way: `Description19, Description2`

Comment: How did you get sortIndex?

Comment: @almasshaikh: i guess that this is what OP asks. How to update the table with `SortIndex` as `int` representing the order?

Comment: yes i'm using SQL server!

Comment: yes, exactly i'm trying to fill out the SortIndex... I want to do something like a group by vehicleId and then fill out the sort index according to the description column

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on `SQL Server`, you can use the following query that uses a ranking function:

```
SELECT StepId, VehicleId, Description, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY VehicleId ORDER BY Description) as SortIndex 
FROM #Vehicle
```

The `row_number()` will generate a number for each row based on its order when sorted by `Description` in it's `VehicleId` group.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way (in my opinion) is to use an updatable CTE with window functions:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by vehicleId order by Description) as NewSortIndex
      from likethat
     )
update toupdate
    set SortIndex = NewSortIndex;
```

If you don't really want an `update` but just to return the results, just use the query in the CTE.